# how to compare between two fingerprint images using samples

Tags: fingerprint

If I have file txt contains binary data for fingerprint image, how can I use these values to compare with another fingerprint image? should I use all these values or just take a sample and if so ... how can I take this sample ?!

Comment: Hope this link would help you, http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint

Answer (score 0):

You should extract a unique Hash from  Fingerprints features and store that text value in the Database. (Enrollment Process)

During Verification Process, you should generate a hash once again from the fingerprint features, it should be an identical hash. Query this hash value in the database.

[Read this Research Paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d6e5/7702367fe8aee5b20d2d3310cc1263e13503.pdf)